# Adding margin of victory to true skill algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, leaderboard

I'm using TrueSkill algorithm to implement a leaderboard of skills for my badminton community. TrueSkill rating uses mainly mean and variance as two parameters to measure skill.

Say for a game of badminton if player A beats player B and the margin of victory (MOV) is 5 - 0 sets. This high MOV indicates player A is way better than player B. How can I incorporate this MOV into trueskill algorithm ?

I'm using python [library](https://trueskill.org/) for the implementation

Comment: My preliminary reading of this algorithm indicates that there is no way to encode an MOV, you could either switch to a different algorithm or not include this data.

Comment: There are hacks that I can think of, but nothing that won't be messy.  (For example you can use the algorithm at the set and game level, then tie them together in some way.)